# É possível alterar o texto do prompt "Add to home screen" de um PWA?

Tags: front-end, pwa

Existe alguma maneira de trocar o texto "Add to home screen" de um PWA? Imaginei que fosse pelo **manifest** do PWA, porém não achei nenhuma especificação, já vi em alguns sites esse texto em português, existe alguma solução?

O meu PWA:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo de como eu queria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a configuração do meu PWA:

```
name: 'Meu App',
lang: 'pt-br',
scope: '/',
short_name: 'MeuApp',
description: 'Meu App PWA',
background_color: '#fff',
theme_color: '#fff',
display: 'standalone',
start_url: '/',
orientation: 'portrait',
icons: [
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-72x72.png',
    sizes: '72x72',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-96x96.png',
    sizes: '96x96',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-128x128.png',
    sizes: '128x128',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-144x144.png',
    sizes: '144x144',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-152x152.png',
    sizes: '152x152',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-192x192.png',
    sizes: '192x192',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-384x384.png',
    sizes: '384x384',
    type: 'image/png'
  },
  {
    src: '/icons/icon-512x512.png',
    sizes: '512x512',
    type: 'image/png'
  }
]
```

Comment: Isto você se refere ao navegador do Android ou do iOS ou esta se referindo a outro local? Se for o "botão" do menu do navegaodor, é característica do navegador e não da página que crioou com capacidade para PWA.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no meu exemplo atual estou me referindo ao prompt no Android mesmo

Comment: O prompt e o botão são parte do navegador e não do seu app, portanto não tem como, mas realmente seria mais interessante se o site com capacidade PWA ficasse como um toolbar automatico do navegador (que tivesse o icone do pwa) com um botão ao invés de ter q ir no menu e depois confirmar em um prompt. PS: ao menos no iOS é ruim, no android é mais pratico, nao testei, é um toolbar já, o texto esta em ingles pq possivelmente seu sistema é em ingles

Comment: PS: o da uol parece que é simulado, não testei já lhe confirmo (peguei um android pra testar)

Comment: Eu imagino que o da UOL não seja o prompt do navegador padrão, se quiser adicionar a resposta de que não existe maneira, a mensagem segue o idioma do browser mesmo, acho que é válido pra quem tiver a mesma dúvida

Comment: Só pra reafirmar, isto que você viu no site UOL é gerado pelo navegador, no entanto meu sistema android esta em inglês e a mensagem aparece em inglês também, a probabilidade é que você tenha aberto o UOL no seu celular pessoal e o PWA em um emulador, mas a mensagem "Add <nome> To HomeScreen" é um toolbar nativo e se o seu sistema operacional for em portugues então vai exibir o texto em português. Segue o print para confirmar, no emular com OS em inglês: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH2QK.png